# MongoDB error when using aggregation: "allowDiskUse" => true

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework, aggregate

I get the mongo error: **Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds** when I use aggregation sort.

In local it works correctly, but on the server it gives an error.

I am using mongo 3.2

This is my aggregation

```
$collection->aggregate(
    [
        array('$unwind' => '$skills.skill'),
        array('$match' => array('skills.skill.name' => $str)),
        array('$unwind' => '$skills.skill.value'),
        array('$sort' => array('skills.skill.value.value' => -1) ),
        array('$group' => array('_id' => null, 'updates' => array('$push' => '$skills.skill.value') )),
        array('$project' =>  array('value' => '$updates'))
    ],
        array("allowDiskUse" => true)
);
```

First, I use aggregation without the `allowDiskUse` option, and I get error: **Sort exceeded memory limit of 104857600 bytes**, then I added option: `allowDiskUse : true` and I get an error: `Read timed out after reading 0 bytes, waited for 30.000000 seconds`

How to solve this problem?

I tried `$cursor->timeout(-1)`, but no results.

Comment: The error  comes from php or httpd, not mongo. You can increase the timeout in `php.ini`, `pool.d/www.conf` `nginx.conf` etc depending on your setup, but it is not advisable. Review your query to run faster, or  application logic to schedule expensive tasks to run them asynchronously.

Comment: You can also greatly increase the performance by simply adding the "additional" `$match` stage as the very first stage in the pipeline `array('$match' => array('skills.skill.name' => $str))`. The reason is that this a the very least matches the "documents" with the condition, which leaves the latter same expression to "filter the array" after `$unwind`. You should **never** begin an aggregation pipeline with `$unwind` or any other stage which cannot possibly use an index or at least otherwise reduce the total documents to process. Adding an index on that field also will help.

Comment: In short, `allowDiskUse` does have it's purpose, but generally it's a "hack", and if you are pointed towards using it by an error then it's usually an indicator of something else you are doing wrong. In this case you failed to filter the matching documents before issuing `$unwind`, which is doing that to every document in your collection.

Comment: thanks )) I did so 

`$result = [];       
 if (!empty($out['skills']['skill'])) {
            foreach ($out['skills']['skill'] as $item) {
                if ($item['name'] == $str) {
                    $result = $item['value'];
                }
            }
        }`